# Reference of the expansion of square root polynomials

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

What is the reference of the formulation given below by Robert israel, please inform me..

Given an even-degree polynomial $$P(x) = a_{2n} x^{2n} + a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1} + \ldots + a_0 = x^{2n} (a_{2n} + a_{2n-1} x^{-1} + \ldots + a_0 x^{-2n}) = a_{2n} x^{2n} (1 + f(1/x)) $$
(where $f(t) = O(t)$ as $t \to 0$) we can write
$$ \sqrt{P(x)} = a_{2n}^{1/2} x^n (1 + f(1/x))^{1/2} = a_{2n}^{1/2} x^n 
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k+1}{4}^{-k} \left( 2
\,k \right) !\,{f(1/x)}^{k}}{ \left( k! \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,k-1
 \right) }}$$
For the "polynomial part", we keep only the terms that end up with a nonnegative power of $x$.
In the example given, $n=3$, $a_6 = 1$ and $f(1/x) = 8 x^{-2} - x^{-3} + \ldots$ so
$$ \sqrt{P(x)} = x^3 \left( 1 + \left(\frac{4}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2x^3}+\ldots\right)+\ldots\right)
= x^3 + 4 x - \frac{1}{2} + \ldots $$

Answer (score 0):

This may be part of an algorithm that tests if a polynomial $p(x)$ can be decomposed into a concatenation $p(x)=f(g(x))$ of lower degree polynomials. Of course, $p(x)=g(x)^2$ would be the most simple case.

There may be something in A. Bini, V. Pan

http://books.google.de/books/about/Polynomial_and_Matrix_Computations.html

or in M. Mignotte

http://books.google.de/books/about/Polynomials.html